How can I down mix stereo to mono audio on a DFPlayer Pro?
I am trying to make an MP3 speaker using a DFPlayer Pro.
The processor generates a DAC left and DAC right which are then fed into a stereo amplifier which generates the L+/- and R+/- to go to the speakers.
In my design, I only have a single mono speaker.
Is there a way to modify the circuit in order to downmix the stereo to mono, either before or after the audio amplifier?
The gain stage seems to be set by the R/C on the DAC signals as shown here:

I have already tried connecting the speaker across L+ and R- (or vice-versa) and I get sound but it is distorted.
I am planning on designing my own PCB and just moving the ICs from the DFPlayer Pro across to my PCB so I have free reign to change the circuit in any way. My current idea is to connect both the resistors R4/R5 to INL to mix the audio (and tying INR to ground as it is unused.) Would I need to change the resistor/capacitor values for this as I believe these set the gain of the amplifier, or would it be better to somehow tie the L+/R+ together to mix the output side instead?
To add to the confusion is the datasheet for the PAM8403states that the minimum resistance for R3/R4 is 18k but they are 5k1 in this design.

You need to sum left and right into mono before the amp and use only one channel of the amp. Use resistors like you suggested in your question to sum left and right together. It's the most cheapest way and good enough way for adequate audio.
You can't sum the audio together after the amp in a reasonable way to drive a speaker.
Also do not tie the unused pin directly to ground. You should either tie it through a capacitor to ground or simply leave it open.

This is a comment, not an answer. An answer would tell the OP how to sum the channels.

@brhans it asks if there is a way. There is. To sum two audio channels together. How exactly to do that is a matter of many details. I could say to use resistors, or I could say to use the worlds most expensive audio op-amps for uselessly high SNR and other audio performance even audiophiles can't hear it.

@Velvet And the body asks if they can be summed with resistors, described already in detail, so "yes you can do it like you suggested" is an answer that does not need to duplicate what was in the question.

While the question asks for how to modify the circuit, as an alternative if you control which MP3 files are used by the player the MP3 files could be converted from stereo to mono before being copied to the DFPlayer Pro.
MPEG Audio Layer I/II/III frame header on the MP3'Tech site shows a MP3 file contains a Channel Mode in the frame header:


00 - Stereo
01 - Joint stereo (Stereo)
10 - Dual channel (2 mono channels)
11 - Single channel (Mono)


How to convert a stereo MP3 to mono MP3 and Converting a bunch of MP3s to mono? on other stacks have some software options for converting MP3 files to mono.
Admittedly I haven't tried this myself to know how well it works.

From a comment:

You can use any method to convert the audio data to be mono in the MP3 file. The fact that MP3 has a separate option of being able to store mono or two channels in different ways has nothing to do with that. For example if you make a CD with mono audio, the same audio data just gets stored into both left and right channels if you want. So you can also downmix the MP3 audio to be monophonic so both left and right channels contain the same data and then re-export it as normal stereo MP3. – Justme

One benefit of converting to a mono MP3 format file, rather than making the MP3 audio monophonic with the same left and right channel content, is to reduce the size of the MP3 file.

This is a good non-electronics solution but does require an extra step if source material is stereo. You can use any method to convert the audio data to be mono in the MP3 file. The fact that MP3 has a separate option of being able to store mono or two channels in different ways has nothing to do with that. For example if you make a CD with mono audio, the same audio data just gets stored into both left and right channels if you want. So you can also downmix the MP3 audio to be monophonic so both left and right channels contain the same data and then re-export it as normal stereo MP3.

I tested. Exported a WAV to MP3 with LAME as Joint Stereo and Mono, using the "Insane 320kbps VBR" settings. The resulting files played back indicated being Stereo and Mono in player, while their MP3 file size was identical in bytes. Surprise. Also if you export with constant bit rate settings say 192 kbps, it must use all the 192 kilobits per second anyway so you just have 192 kilobits per second available to store Mono, or 192 kilobits per second to store Stereo. And mostly MP3 do not store the audio as two separate channels, you get better quality with Joint Stereo. Same file size again.
